# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the following code in order to classify MNIST images:

```
import random
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(raw_input(), raw_input(), raw_input())

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The first 3 lines were given in the exercise that I was doing and the rest of the lines I copied from the Tensorflow tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

The problem is that I am getting

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1000, 28, 28, 1) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape (Dimension(None), Dimension(10))
```

on the last line.

I think the problem is with the `mnist` object. It's of type `input_data.DataSets` but I don't know what's inside of it and I don't know how to check what's inside.

If I run `print(mnist.test.labels)`, I get `[[[[0]`, which is very confusing.

So any idea how to fix this code?

Comment: You are feeding incorrect shape data to placeholder. What exactly is "mnist" doing ? Where did you get that from ? Usually, this is the file used to download mnist "https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py". Its  calling is shown in TF MNIST example here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist

Comment: Could you provide code of your input_data function/file ?